# How to refresh an image after src change in Angular JS

Tags: image-processing, angularjs

I would like to selecta file and load it in angular js.

Everything work fine, the only problem the image don't refrech. I can see that everything work because when i toggle the on menu on my page with angular.js the image is been refreshing.

Here is my code :

```
<div ng-controller="TopMenuCtrl">
        <button class="btn" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">Toggle collapse</button>
        <input ng-model="photo"
           onchange="angular.element(this).scope().file_changed(this)"
           type="file" accept="image/*" multiple />
            <output id="list"></output>
            <img ng-src="{{imageSource}}">
    </div>
```

And the Angular js script :

```
$scope.file_changed = function(element) {
          var files = element.files; // FileList object
          // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
          for (var i = 0, photofile; photofile = files[i]; i++) { 

             // var photofile = element.files[0];
              var reader = new FileReader();
              reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
                    return function(e) {

                    $scope.imageSource= e.target.result;

                    };
                  })(photofile);

              reader.readAsDataURL(photofile);
            };

  }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You must call [Scope.$apply](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$apply) when you manually update `$scope.imageSource` in the `onLoad` function, because Angular can't guess when you make this change.